# UX/UI Design College Club

Tags: community

As the title says, I'm starting a college club based on UI/UX Design. Since the college is based on informatics, programming and web development, Web Design is very very related to this, although there are not any courses provided by the school. The purpose of the club is to give an idea about this field for those who may be interested in a design career, and to help improve those who already have some knowledge, therefore making a beautiful community.

The question is, what fun activities do you suggest we do ? The learning plan is on point, but I don't want to turn the club meetings into generic college classes. I think it's a good idea to do something fun and creative while learning, to keep them excited and willing to get better.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very beneficial thing you are doing, and I definitely would like to encourage you to keep it up (and others working in various organizations to do the same).

Some things off the top of my head that helps me with professional development:

Along the lines of the 'doing some design' category:

- Participate in hackathons (sometimes very close to real-life work situations than you think)
- Trying to pick something in the real-world to redesign (good for portfolio as well as Medium articles)

Along the lines of the 'review and reflect' category:

- Do a design critique of something that you have seen or designed yourself
- Write a Medium article on something you are passionate about in UX design (mine is ethical design practices)

Something that I definitely encourage more as part of being in a community of practice:

- Ask AND answer questions on UXSE (this one's a no-brainer)
- Ask AND answer questions on Quora
- Ask AND answer questions on reddit